# Fastest/cleanest way to pad data with zero-data

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I want to pad a set of data in `{x, y}` pairs with `{x, 0}`, `{x, 0}` on each side of each data point.

I know I can do this like so:

```
zeroPaddedData[xdata_, ydata_] :=

 With[{padding = 
    Transpose[{xdata, ConstantArray[0., Length@xdata]}]},
  Append[
   Riffle[
    Riffle[
     padding,
     Transpose[{xdata, ydata}]
     ],
    padding,
    3
    ],
   {xdata[[-1]], 0.}
   ]
  ]
```

which, for example, gives:

```
zpd = zeroPaddedData @@ Transpose@Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .5}]

{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0.479426}, {0.5, 
  0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.841471}, {1., 0.}, {1.5, 0.}, {1.5, 
  0.997495}, {1.5, 0.}, {2., 0.}, {2., 0.909297}, {2., 0.}, {2.5, 
  0.}, {2.5, 0.598472}, {2.5, 0.}, {3., 0.}, {3., 0.14112}, {3., 
  0.}, {3.5, 0.}, {3.5, -0.350783}, {3.5, 0.}, {4., 
  0.}, {4., -0.756802}, {4., 0.}, {4.5, 0.}, {4.5, -0.97753}, {4.5, 
  0.}, {5., 0.}, {5., -0.958924}, {5., 0.}, {5.5, 
  0.}, {5.5, -0.70554}, {5.5, 0.}, {6., 0.}, {6., -0.279415}, {6., 0.}}
```

Which will plot out like so:

```
zpd // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

But this is slow over larger data sets:

```
dats = Transpose@Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .001}];

zeroPaddedData @@ dats // RepeatedTiming // First

0.0039
```

How can I do this faster/cleaner?

Comment: Is `zpd` not ending with `{6., 0.}` deliberate?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less nope I just accidentally a result from before I added the `Append`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) and [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape) on the original `data`:

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray @ Table[
    {x, Sin[x]},
    {x, 0, 2Pi, .0001}
];
```

Then:

```
ArrayReshape[
    data . {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}},
    {Length[data] 3, 2}
]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000397, Null}

Answer (score 6):

One reason for slowness is that the input data was not packed. Moreover `Transpose` is often faster than `Riffle`:

```
{xdata, ydata} = Transpose[Map[x \[Function] {x, Sin[x]}, Range[0., 2 Pi, .0001]]];

f[xdata_, ydata_] := Transpose[{
   Flatten[Transpose[ConstantArray[xdata, 3]]],
   With[{o = ConstantArray[0., Length[ydata]]},
    Flatten[Transpose[{o, ydata, o}]]
    ]
   }]

a = zeroPaddedData[xdata, ydata]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = f[xdata, ydata]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b
```

> 0.030
>
> 0.00165
>
> True

Answer (score 5):

Slower but simple

```
tab = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .5}];
SequenceReplace[tab, {{a_,b_}}:>Sequence[{a,0},{a,b},{a,0}]] == zpd
```

> True

**Update:** Using `Upsample` on the second argument gives a slight improvement over Henrik's `f`:

```
ClearAll[zPad]
zPad[xd_, yd_] := Transpose[{Flatten[ConstantArray[xd, 3], {2, 1}], Upsample[yd, 3, 2]}];

{xdata, ydata} = Transpose[Map[x \[Function] {x, Sin[x]}, Range[0., 2 Pi, .0001]]]; 
a = zeroPaddedData[xdata, ydata]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.024

```
b = f[xdata, ydata]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0017

```
c = zPad[xdata, ydata]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0016

```
a == b == c
```

> True

Interesting to note that although `Upsample` is almost twice as fast as `With[{o = ConstantArray[0., Length[ydata]]}, Flatten[Transpose[{o, ydata, o}] ]]` this advantage is not retained when combined with other steps:

```
r1 = Upsample[ydata, 3, 2] ; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.00061

```
r2 = With[{o = ConstantArray[0., Length[ydata]]}, 
     Flatten[Transpose[{o, ydata, o}] ]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0013

```
r1 == r2
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

```
With[{a = data.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}]}, {a, data, a} // Transpose //Catenate] == zpd
```

> True

*Original Post*

```
data // {#.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}], #, #.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}]} & //Transpose //Catenate
```